# Regex to replace first two characters and last characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and I need to remove the first two characters, in addition to the last character. I've managed to successfully remove the first two, but how do I remove the last character?

```
var code = 'AB123ABCD4';
code.replace(/^[\s\S]{0,2}/g, "");
```

This removes the first two!

Comment: While `^` matches the beginning of a string, `$` matches its end.

Comment: `code.replace(/(^.{2})|(.{2}$)/g,'')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method to achieve the result.

```js
var code = 'AB123ABCD4';
console.log(code.slice(2,-2));
```

---

With regex, you can use the [vertical bar](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to separate 2 patterns and [end anchor(`$`)](https://www.google.com/search?q=end%20anchor%20regex&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN866IN866&oq=end%20anchor%20regex&aqs=chrome.0.0l4.4835j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for line end assertion.

```js
var code = 'AB123ABCD4';
console.log(code.replace(/^[\s\S]{0,2}|[\s\S]{0,2}$/g, ""));
```

Comment: Wow, smart thinking!